# Cannot connect to my postgres database through docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a very simple docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
      POSTGRES_DB: demo
```

And start it with: docker-compose up -d
It starts well:

```
Creating network "bootcamp_default" with the default driver
Creating bootcamp_db_1 ... done

Name: bootcamp_db_1
Command: docker-entrypoint.sh postgres
State: up
Ports: 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp,:::5432->5432/tcp
```

When I go into the container I see that demo db exists, but when I try to connect to it any utils say that demo db is not existed. 
How can I connect to it?

Comment: And I tried to clean up any docker volumes before starting my container.

Comment: Connect to it how?  From where?  What's the result?

Comment: @DavidMaze, I tried to connect to it through DBeaver and Intellij Idea DB manager - they say that demo db doesn't exist. My settings in DBeaver: Host: localhost ; Port: 5432 ; Database: demo ; Username: postgres ; Password: my_pass  .

Comment: password should be my_password

Comment: @DefSoudani All credentials are correct, the problem is that instead of localhost i have to use something else to connect to the docker container, my system (i'm on win10) doesn't go to the container when i'm using localhost that's why it says there's no my existed db.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by moving the project to Ubuntu system. It was caused by OS settings.